# Alpha blending is slow on linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, swt, alphablending

we are developing an SWT/RCP(Eclipse 3.5) application on both Windows and Linux (on identical hardware).
The application is a GIS app which shows several layered maps(PNG images) rendered with alpha blending.

```
org.eclipse.draw2d.Graphics.setAlpha(...);
org.eclipse.draw2d.Graphics.drawImage(...);
```

On Windows the performance is pretty good, but on Linux it is very poor.

is that a Linux(GTK/KDE) problem?
or is there any workaround to improve the performance on Linux?

Comment: There might be a lot of reasons. What is the graphics card? Does Linux use hardware acceleration? What is the window manager? Is it a Compositing window manager? Have you checked if SWT uses hardware acceleration behind the scenes?