# SWT draw2d alpha blending

Tags: java, swt, alpha, blending, draw2d

I'm looking for some method to draw half transparent figures within the draw2d framework. 
Currently I'm using `setAlpha()` of `org.eclipse.draw2d.Graphics`. The problem is that it slows down the whole UI, if I draw more than one half transparent figure.

Here was another question regarding the perfomance of it [`[1]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847451/swt-rcp-alpha-blending-is-slow-on-linux). It targets SWT on Linux, I target both Linux and Windows. The windows (Win7) system has a 3D capable graphic card and a i7 q720. The Linux machine is even better equipped and has also 3D, so I think it's not a performance issue of the platform.

My **question** is: Is there a performant way to achieve alpha blending in draw2d?

I've tried to use OpenGL respectivly LWJGL. Since draw2d and OpenGL can't be mixed up and I must rely on draw2d, I thought I could do something like this: draw2d -> OpenGL -> draw2d
[here](http://pastebin.com/hGHFR50C) where `canvas` is the Canvas where the OpenGL drawing happens and `c1` is the Canvas where I want to get the drawn OpenGL picture. But my [attempt](http://pastebin.com/30z3hVzg) to copy the OpenGL drawings doesn't work it gets me just the underlying Canvas (`canvas`) background. Besides this I'm not sure if this would improve the "perormance" anyway...

Thanks, 
atx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is known but unsolved. On the mailing list of draw2d there is a thread regarding this issue: [mailing list](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=68724)

TL;DR: A possible solution was dropped because of license issues between LWJGL and Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your src/dest images are of the same depth (eg. ARGB)
Otherwise, expensive conversions happen during copy (src->dest)

GCs don't allow access to their underlying buffers, afaik.
MemoryImageSource might be a way to go.

You can grab your OpenGL drawing images using something like:

```
BufferedImage capture  = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle( canvas.getX(), canvas.getY(), canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight() ) );
```

Kind of fiddly, but very fast.

I use it to save jpegs of my live animation frames to a folder.

VirtualDub then creates a movie from the frames. Have to play with the frame rate ;)

Great for producing youtube teasers!
[You can see one here!](http://www.standard3d.com)

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I solved my problem by implementing the half done LwjglGraphics implementation of org.eclipse.draw3d and integrating it into org.eclipse.draw2d. works like a charm.